# Binding Pie Chart with WPF Toolkit not showing points

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, charts

I have a piechart that I have defined as below:

```
        <chartingToolkit:Chart DataContext="1,10 2,20 3,30 4,40" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="334,238,0,0" 
                           Name="chart1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="177"
                           Width="218" BorderBrush="#00000000">
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries 
        ItemsSource="{Binding PieCollection}"
        IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"
        DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Share}" />
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

And my xaml is also referenced here:

```
 xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit">
```

So no problem there. I have a dataset I declare in my ViewModel:

```
 private ObservableCollection<PiePoint> _pieCollection;
 public ObservableCollection<PiePoint> PieCollection { get { return _pieCollection; } set { _pieCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("PieCollection"); } }
```

Where PiePoint is an object I define like so:

```
    public class PiePoint
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Int16 Share { get; set; }
    }
```

When I start up my ViewModel in my constructor, I added some test data points here to see if I could get some data on my chart:

```
    PieCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePoint>();
    PieCollection.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Mango", Share = 10 });
    PieCollection.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Banana", Share = 36 });
```

But nothing shows up on the chart. The breakpoint hits, I see the chart's background, and I know that the items source is bound to the right collection, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I got using your data:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="0" Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.DataContext>
            <local:PieCollection/>
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.DataContext>
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" DependentValuePath="Share" IndependentValuePath="Name" DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" >
        </chartingToolkit:PieSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]

Notice that I'm creating the `PieCollection` within XAML, so it is associated with the `DataContext` for the chart. In your case you're creating your `PieCollection` in code behind, so you probably need to do something like

```
chart.DataContext = PieCollection
```

**EDIT**: creating `PieCollection` dynamically:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    PieCollection pieCollection1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pieCollection1 = new PieCollection();

        pieCollection1.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Mango", Share = 10 });
        pieCollection1.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Banana", Share = 36 });
        pieCollection1.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Grapes", Share = 15 });
        pieCollection1.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Apple", Share = 20 });

        Chart1.DataContext = pieCollection1;
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The reason i'm creating my PieCollection in the behind code is because the values are dynamically changing. Also, since it is in a viewmodel, I won't be able to have access to my pie chart object to keep the interfaces separate.

Comment: Like I said, you're not assigning `PieCollection` to `DataContext`. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also, I think you don't need this in your XAML: `DataContext="1,10 2,20 3,30 4,40"`. Take it out.