# How to create a simple Pie chart using Extended WPF Toolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, toolkit, xceed

I'm fairly new to C# development.
I'm trying to create a simple Pie chart using Visual Studio, C# and Extended WPF Toolkit. The code that follows is a part of a dll i'm trying to build (plug in for Revit).
I installed Extended WPF Toolkit using NuGet.
I was not able to find any tutorial or examples, so i tried to put up the code from some pieces i found on differnt online sources.
At the moment, i have

```
xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <xctk:Pie x:Name="foobar"
                  DataContext="{Binding PieCollection, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
        </xctk:Pie>
    </Grid>
```

and

```
public class PiePoint
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int16 Share { get; set; }
}

public class CompareToMultiLODViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private ObservableCollection<PiePoint> _pieCollection;

    public ObservableCollection<PiePoint> PieCollection
    {
        get { return _pieCollection; }
        set { _pieCollection = value; OnPropertyChanged("PieCollection"); }
    }
public CompareToMultiLODViewModel()
    {
        CompareToMultiLODBtnCommand = new MRCommand(this);

        PieCollection = new ObservableCollection<PiePoint>();
        PieCollection.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Mango", Share = 10 });
        PieCollection.Add(new PiePoint { Name = "Banana", Share = 36 });
    }

    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _PropertyChanged;

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            //((INotifyPropertyChanged)PieCollection).PropertyChanged += value;
            _PropertyChanged += value;
        }

        remove
        {
            //((INotifyPropertyChanged)PieCollection).PropertyChanged -= value;
            _PropertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        _PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
```

The code behind xaml is

```
    public partial class CompareToMultiLOD : Page
{
    public CompareToMultiLOD()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new CompareToMultiLODViewModel();
    }
```

I do not know if it's relevant, but when debugging i see that DataContext is assigned before the PieCollection is created, and then OnPropertyChanged is triggered once, on PieCollection initialization. PropertyChanged seems to be triggered once (which i do not understand, since i add two values).

I am not sure that ViewModel is the right place to store data that Pie chart uses, but i placed it there temporaly (since it's a mock class, obviously).

At the moment i would just like to make it work.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Pie` is not really a chart with data series but a shape that represents a single portion of an ellipse: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/PieChart.

If you want a pie chart you should take a look at [this NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFToolkit.DataVisualization/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841953/binding-pie-chart-with-wpf-toolkit-not-showing-points) answer for an example of how to use it to create a pie chart.

This should give you a pie chart:

```
xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
...
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Margin="0" Title="Chart Title" DataContext="{Binding PieCollection}">
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                   DependentValuePath="Share" 
                                   IndependentValuePath="Name">
        </chartingToolkit:PieSeries>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing that out, the name was completely misleading.
Is it really recommended to use WPF toolkit, since the last update was more than 7 years ago? For a framework, that sounds as old as dinosaurs to me.

Comment: @MarijaRakic: Questions asking to recommend or find a tool or software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they are based on opinions.

Comment: I understand. It was more of a wonder how come that there is no newer, more popular library. Thanks a lot!